# Edit Text content in Weebly editor page through Ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, watir, weebly

Following are the actions I tried to edit the TEXT content through Ruby Watir after drag and drop of TEXT is done in Weebly editor page:

```
click
fire_event :click
dblclick
fire_event "onclick"
send_keys [:shift, :end, :delete]
fire_event("dblclick")
send_keys :enter
double_click
```

None of the above actions are working to edit the TEXT content in Weebly editor page. Can anyone please help what are the possibilities to make it work through Ruby Watir?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be you are fire the events against the wrong element.
They are doing there lot of JS replacements using generated ids to identify what is attached to what, this could help you quickly determined all the elements you are playing with

@browser.element(xpath => '//*[contains(text(),"Text I put in manually")]').click
If that can click the right element then you need to find a way how to identify it better. But it could be that the click is only accepted by the Parent element(if they restricted bubbling trough JS).

also you could try to execute arbitrary JS to debug what is going on.
https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2015/07/23/returning-watir-element-from-execute_script/